# Prevent swipe to go back on first page in flutter

Tags: flutter, swipe, program-entry-point, back

I have an issue that even when I'm on the main page, the user can still swipe back (from the edge) and hence end up on a black page, how do I prevent this?

Best regards

Comment: Could you please post some code to reproduce your problem? What function are you using to show the main page?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include how you set the main page to be opened by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some more info here: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/addScopedWillPopCallback.html

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(//forbidden swipe in iOS(my ThemeData(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,)
        onWillPop: ()async {
            if (Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress)
            return false;
            else
            return true;
        },
        child: <your child>,
        );
    }
```