# Flutter: willpopscope not working while InAppWebview : Need Swipe back to Navigate Back in IOS ( Flutter InAppWebView)

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I have used this code and it will work perfectly in Android but I need this thing in IOS

`WillPopScope(onWillPop: () => Future.value(false), child: _main(context));`

also, I have check out these links:

[1) Stackoverflow disable swipe back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161644/flutter-disable-swipe-to-navigate-back-in-ios-and-android)

[2) Github InappWebview swipe back issue from the package itself](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203)

but **my question is the opposite one**: how to prevent swiping back

-> if you observe inAppWebview it will stop working swipe back only for the first page but all other ( inner pages ) will work perfectly I want to stop swipe back all pages without use of gesture detect

so is there ant way to do this?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724096/11675817

Comment: i have already tried that one but it's not working in case where child widget is InAppWebview.

Comment: @amit.flutter Were you ever able to resolve this? Driving me nuts.

Comment: @scoots i research a lot but both things are not possible together so simply i added web page back and forward button ( like google crome button ) in app bar at right corner and left side main BACK button to close webview and navigate to back to home or previous button

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot but it's not possible to swipe either we can override the whole method from scratch in IOS or a simple solution is that we can add forward and backward button in the app bar of the app

> 1)Solution 1 ( Adding forward and backward buttons for the web and main back button to close WEBVIEW page)

[image]

> 2. Solution 2 ( Overrideing IOS Methods )

```
class CustomMaterialPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
@protected
  bool get hasScopedWillPopCallback {
    return false;
  }
  CustomMaterialPageRoute({
    @required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  }) : super(
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
          maintainState: maintainState,
          fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog,
        );
}
```

> checkout fill answe here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203#issuecomment-540663717

> another useful link: 1) https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_will_pop_scope 2) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203#issuecomment-1172824709 3) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203#issuecomment-1193809403

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but I leave an answer. In my experience, swipe is bound to be a problem if I use inappwebview in iOS. Fortunately, however, I found one solution.

First, Use the inappwebview package in 6.xx version.

Second, Add the following properties to `initialSettings` in InAppWebView widget.

```
 initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
    allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures: false,
      …
      …
    ),
```

Additional attributes that can help you control webview of ios in `initialSettings`: `sharedCookiesEnabled`, `allowsLinkPreview`, `disallowOverScroll`